# My Issue: 低額. Does it mean low-cost or small amount?

Tags: word-usage

Full text: 低額ATM回線サービス(*5)に対応するATM25M/ATM155Mモジュールや、ISDNネットサービスを利用した回線バックアップに対応するBRI/PRIモジュールを装備可能です。

My understanding: It can be equipped with ATM25M/ATM155M modules that support ATM circuit services(*5) and BRI/PRI modules that support circuit backup using ISDN network services.

Comment: Do you mean that whether 低額 can describe something other than money? Then no.

Comment: @brocoli facemask Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

低額 always refers to a price and means "inexpensive".

Comment: Thank you for your help!